# Uncaught runtime errors: dispatcher is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am following this tutorial on YouTube
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M]
and I have followed each step carefully, installing the required packages.
Despite the tutorial, I haven't installed the Bootstrap package.
So far, this is my App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component.js"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />      
      <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

and I haven't touched any other files in the src folder.

This is the Navbar component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Navbar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">ExcerTracker</Link>
        <div className="collpase navbar-collapse">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="navbar-item">
          <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Exercises</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-item">
          <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Exercise Log</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-item">
          <Link to="/user" className="nav-link">Create User</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

and the exercises-list.component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ExercisesList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


My package.json file: 

{
  "name": "mern-exercise-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.22.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
dispatcher is null
useRef@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:73943:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70161:55
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20190:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23474:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24770:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9786:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9830:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9887:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29751:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28999:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28922:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28895:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28290:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36302:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36280:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36517:25
```

Can someone please help me out here? Thanks in advance!

I have tried re-installing react-router-dom and react-router packages. I expected the application to show the Navbar component, but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: You have React-Router-DOM v6 as a dependency, but you are using the v5 code syntax. Are you *sure* you have correctly installed all the correct project dependencies, correctly?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for your response! I have run npm install react-router-dom in the project directory. I may be using outdated code syntax because the tutorial I am following is 4 years old..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue in the code *other than* using the older React-Router-DOM v5 code syntax when you have v6 installed as a dependency.

See if updating to use the V6 components and props resolves the issue.

- All `Route` components need to be rendered by the `Routes` component that handles matching routes to the URL path.
- The `Route` component renders all content on the `element` prop ***as JSX*** instead of a reference to a React compmonent.
- All routes are now always exactly matched, there is no `exact` `Route` prop.
- `react-router-dom` re-exports ***all*** of `react-router`, there's no need to include both as project dependencies. Uninstall `react-router` and remove it from the `package.json` file. Running `npm uninstall --save react-router` should be sufficient for this.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component.js"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />      
      <br/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<ExercisesList />} />
      </Routes?
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The error I think implies there's an issue with React, specifically with React hooks, so please also ensure you have `react` correctly installed as a dependency.